# Transform div and move position on scroll? .scrollTop, .css transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am looking for a simple solution to move and scale an object from one place to another.

I have made a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkjmuLLk/1/) with this code. The problem is I need it to stop getting smaller at some point. So it has a minimum size, the other problem is I would like it to both scale smaller and move left? Can I achieve this with matrix?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    $(".fade-on-scroll").css("transform", "scale(" + (1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700) + ")");

});
```

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Would reducing the height be a good enough solution? `.side { height: 900px; }`

Comment: I am afraid not. I need it to function in any height. It needs to stop before its completely gone.

Comment: ok, what about moving left.. where should it reach? until it touches the left side of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pre-calculate the scale. That way you can enforce restrictions.

```
var scale = (1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 700)
if (scale < .2) scale = .2
```

For position, see [translate (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate). You can set both scale and translate (i.e. `transform: scale(...) translate(...)`) on the same line.